# How to modify the callback in a custom validator in Symfony2(.7)

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

The title might seem awkward, but the reason for doing is is the re-use of code.

Say I have a Form(type), an Entity and the validation on the entity as annotation.

For example :

**the form:**

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
    ->add('country', 'choice', [
        'choices' => $entity->getLocations(),
        'required' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'label' => 'Are you located in:',
    ])
```

**the entity :**

```
/**
 * @Assert\Choice(callback = "getLocations")
 */
protected $country;

#.....

public static function getLocations()
{
    return array( 'en-wa' => 'England/Wales', 'sc' => 'Scotland');
}
```

Now of couse the validation will always fail because it works with values rather than with keys, so I was thinking of writing a custom validator called KeyChoice so I can still use the callback. but I can't seem to find any documentation about this, and reading the source didn't help out either.

Now I don't want judgement about best practice unless there is a way where I only have to define the options ones / form or even less, like for example in the form type, but then how do I use them in the callback in the validator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
/**
 * @Assert/Choice(callback="getLocationChoices")
 */
 ...

 public static function getLocationChoices(){

  return array_keys(self::getLocations());
 }
```

### Update:

Or you can create a [custom constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) for that:

```
// the constraint
namespace AppBundle\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class KeyChoice extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'the choice is not valid';
    public $callback;
}

// the validator
namespace AppBundle\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\ConstraintDefinitionException;

class KeyChoiceValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!is_callable($choices = array($this->context->getClassName(), $constraint->callback))
            && !is_callable($choices = $constraint->callback)
        ) {
            throw new ConstraintDefinitionException('The Choice constraint expects a valid callback');
        }
        $choices = call_user_func($choices);   
        if(!in_array($value, $choices)){
          $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();
        }    
    }
}
```

You can then use this constraint as stated in the linked doc.However this will not provide any of the other functionality that the choice constraint provides, if you want to have those you have to extend **both** `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Choice` and `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\ChoiceValidator`, don't override anything in the `ChoiceConstraint` but you have to override the `ChoiceConstraintValidator::validate` completely and copy paste it, then add a `$choices = array_keys($choices);` at [this line](https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/master/Constraints/ChoiceValidator.php#L62)

Comment: that requires an exta function in the entity, the point is that i got 20 odd entities and although i could stick that in a trait, i was looking for a better solution, it's certainly a valid answer but not the answer i was looking for

Comment: thx for the update, over the weekend i wrote some more custom validators and I could have probably figured it out on my own but i guess i was waiting for a solution that ties in better with forms, but this is good enough for me, cheers